# What skins can knives come in?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What skins can they be unboxed in?  I cant find any official answer, either on the wiki or on the internet.

Comment: Are you referring to item exteriors (Battle-Scarred, Well-Worn, Factory New etc)? Or maybe the item finishes (Blue Steel, Crimson Web, Night etc)? Or both, or? :)

Comment: I'm talking about effects, not the quality of the item

Comment: Can you give an example of an "effect" then, as I am not sure what you are referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a list of current knife skins in cs go:

http://kniferound.net/wiki/Weapon_Finishes#Exceedingly_Rare_Knives